# Centered Variable Width Text with "dot dot dot" animation

Tags: html, css, centering

http://pastebin.com/index/9M2rA8cx that has all my code.

You will notice that the two div's are centered in large.css. However, the text is being re-centered after each '.' is applied. If I put the span id="wait" outside the centered div, it will show up in the upper left corner. I don't need exact centering, but I can't use a absolute position for centering because the text changes.

Is there any way to append the "..." to the already centered text without it re-centering?

thanks!

Comment: Please create a functional example on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just apply a fixed width style to the `wait` span, such as:

```
span.wait{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Genius. Also, if anyone else happens to do this as well, make sure to set the text-align to left for the wait span. Although I made a class and put this stuff in a div.